# Where to place the provider widget in the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I'am trying to understand how to use provider and where to place the provider widget.

Therefore I build an app from a tutorial using provider. Here you can see the [widget tree according to the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2xGn.jpg). The provider widget is wrapped around the MaterialApp widget and the arrows show, which widget uses which other widget.

As far as I understand, in general, the provider widget is supposed to be placed as far down the widget tree as possible and only as far up as neccessary. As neither MaterialApp, NavigationBase, Scaffold nor IndexedStack need information from the providers, I thought I could move those down the tree. But this doesn't work: When I wrap MultiProvider around Scaffold (or any other widget below MaterialApp as far as I tried it) I get an exception.

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<StudentsProvider> above this StudentsListScreen Widget
```

Apparently - although having read a lot on provider - I haven't fully understood how provider interacts. What did I miss?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Just keep in mind that if you navigate from 1 page to another, a parallel widget tree is created at the material app for the new route. (You can verify this using widget inspector in dev tools) This means that if you wrap your first page with Provider, the second page will not have access to it as the parallel widget tree does not have access to it. Everywhere else it should work as you'd expect.

Comment: @AjilO. Thank you. That seems to be the problem in this case. Apparently there's still a lot for me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The provider must be located at the very top of the tree above the MaterialApp widget and declared once. Then in this case the provider's data will be available from any widget within the tree.

```
...
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [...],
  child: MaterialApp(
    ...someAppSettings,
   home: HomeWidget()
)
```

Everything inside the MaterialApp widget (even when moving between different routes) will have access to the data from the provider.

I use this structure in my application and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was already answered by Ajil O. but as it was a comment, I couldn't mark it as answered.